# How to add a foreign key relationship in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

there are two tables

```
create table A(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    subject text not null,
);

create table B(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    text integer references A(id)
        on delete restrict
        deferrable initially deferred
        unique
);
```

`B` table row should be linked to `A`.
So, I added `B.text` with a foreign key to `A`..

I added few random data with pk values 1 and 2 in table A
Now, I tried to create B table data with a `text` value referring to `5` which is not present in A but it still could store..

Why this is working and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable foreign keys support:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Example:

```
sqlite> create table A(
   ...>     id integer primary key autoincrement,
   ...>     subject text not null
   ...> );
sqlite> 
sqlite> create table B(
   ...>     id integer primary key autoincrement,
   ...>     text integer references A(id)
   ...>         on delete restrict
   ...>         deferrable initially deferred
   ...>         unique
   ...> );
sqlite> insert into a values(1,1),(2,2);
sqlite> insert into b(text) values(3);
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys=on;
sqlite> insert into b(text) values(4);
Error: foreign key constraint failed
sqlite>
```